# Breaking ruby array into multiple arrays depending on common attributes

Tags: ruby, arrays

Suppose I have an array of objects as:

```
[ obj1, obj2, obj3 ...... objn ]
```

where each object has an attribute, say `A`.

How can I break this array into multiple arrays with each array containing objects with the same value for `A`? What will be a cleanest implementation?

Comment: need too explicit examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[ obj1, obj2, obj3 ...... objn ].group_by(&:A).values
```